# How to store checkpoint into remote RocksDB in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, rocksdb, checkpoint

I know that there are three kinds of state backends in Apache Flink: MemoryStateBackend, FsStateBackend and RocksDBStateBackend.

MemoryStateBackend stores the checkpoints into local RAM, FsStateBackend stores the checkpoints into local FileSystem, and RocksDBStateBackend stores the checkpoints into RocksDB. I have some questions about the RocksDBStateBackend.

As my understanding, the mechanism of RocksDBStateBackend has been embedded into Apache Flink. The rocksDB is a kind of key-value DB. So If I'm right, it means that Flink will store all checkpoints into the embedded rocksDB, which uses the local disk.

If so, I think the disk could be exhausted in some cases because of the checkpoints stored into the rocksDB. Now I'm thinking if it is possible to configure a remote rocksDB to store these checkpoints? If it is possible, should we worry about the remote rocksDB crashing? If the remote rocksDB crashes, the jobs of Flink can not continue working, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to use an external or remote RocksDB with Apache Flink. RocksDB is an embedded key-value store with a local instance in each task manager.

Several points:

- Flink makes a strong distinction between the working state, which is always local (for good performance), and state snapshots (checkpoints and savepoints), which are not local (for reliability they should be stored in a distributed file system).
- The RocksDBStateBackend uses the local disk for working state. The other two state backends keep their working state on the Java heap.
- The checkpoint coordinator arranges for all of these slices of data scattered across all of the task managers to be collected together into complete checkpoints that are stored elsewhere. In the case of the MemoryStateBackend those checkpoints are stored on the JobManager heap; for the other two, they are in a distributed file system.

You want to configure RocksDB to use the fastest available local file system. Try to use locally attached SSDs, and avoid network-attached storage (such as EBS). Do not try to use a distributed file system such as S3 as RocksDB's local storage.

`state.backend.rocksdb.localdir` controls where each local RocksDB stores its working state.

The parameter to the RocksDBStateBackend constructor controls where the checkpoints are stored. E.g., using S3 as recommended by @ezequiel is the obvious choice on AWS.

Comment: Seems like usecase that flink current architecture performs better where state is not expected to grow forever. For example, If using inner join in flink sql that requires state persistent of both side then working state can not be all on local state.. when it is not available locally then it searches desired records in all the incremental checkpoints right?

Comment: The working state is always local. Checkpoints are only read during failure recovery, otherwise they play no role.

Comment: Thanks for clarification David. For scenarios where Rate of change for a record from a source is nondeterministic(sometime 1k/day and sometime none for a months). Since it is record that is changed, it will always land to same taskslot hence same rocksdb and local state that will eventually exceed the local disk storage capacity, correct? In that case, task manager will simply fail or there is some recommendations how to handle it without thinking about externalizing the rocksdb with heavy resource allocation?

Comment: May be some configuration where rocksdb purge the older history and maintains latest record (not time based where record is purged if no update happened, we have to keep at-least 1 record to make a join) in level0 through compaction? use case is flink-sql with streaming

Comment: RocksDB will automatically compact away the older history. You won't run out of local disk unless your keyspace grows in an unbounded fashion.

Answer (score 0):

RocksDB can work with any supported Filesystem by Flink
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/filesystems/

If you are running Flink probably you want to checkpoint, and resume from them.

I would externalise the storage outside the node. I you are using a cloud provider like AWS, then S3 is the right option.

So you should probably write something like:
`new RocksDBStateBackend("s3://my-bucket", true);` and assing it to your execution environment.

Please check the above documentation to configure properly your filesystem.

Comment: FYI, `RocksDBStateBackend(checkpoint-storage-location)` was deprecated a few years ago in favor of having a cleaner separation of the choice of state backend vs specifying where the checkpoints are to be stored.