# Is there any advantage of using external rocksdb vs internal in flink

Tags: apache-flink

Are there any performance/Scalability benefits of using external rocksdb vs internal while using flink.

Internal rocksdb

> StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment(); env.setStateBackend(new FsStateBackend("hdfs://namenode:40010/flink/checkpoints"));

Or is it at all possible to configure external rocksdb at all or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store checkpoint into remote RocksDB in Apache Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61655220/how-to-store-checkpoint-into-remote-rocksdb-in-apache-flink)

Comment: As per this post, it looks like we cannot configure external rocksdb with flink. Thanks for sharing the link

Comment: It’s not only impossible, but also undesirable.